# How can I put a null value for char** str

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, off-by-one

How can I put a null value for char** str because im having and Error of "Dereference of out of bound pointer: 1 bytes(1element) past end of array im using C language"

```
while(part)
    {
        res = (char**)realloc(res, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        *(res + i) = mystrdup(part);

        part = mystrdup(strtok(NULL, delim));
        i++;
    }
    res = (char**)realloc(res, i * sizeof(char*));
    *(res + i) = NULL; // This is where I Encounter the ERROR
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Does your question concern C++? How?

Comment: Isn't it like after the `realloc()`,  `*(res + i) = NULL;` should be `*(res + i -1) = NULL;` or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean with "null value"? The value `0x0`? A _null pointer_?

Comment: When I use *(res + i) = NULL i got an error of Dereference of out of bound but when I use *(res + i -1) = NULL if my last data inside the res[2] = C it will become null value, the only retain data will be in res[0] = A, res[1] = B. Then for the res[3]=NULL, because this *(res + i -1) = NULL will delete the last value of my array. That's what I get when I use this *(res + i -1) = NULL

Answer (score 2):

In this part of code

```
res = (char**)realloc(res, i * sizeof(char*));
*(res + i) = NULL;
```

by trying to access `*(res + i)`, you're going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). You should write

```
*(res + i -1) = NULL;
```

Having said that,

- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- A statement like `pointerP = realloc (pointerP, .....)` is considered very unsafe, as in case, if `realloc()` fails, you'll end up losing the actual pointer, too.
- Always check for the return value of `malloc()` and family of functions against `NULL` to ensure the success.
- Also, put a NULL check for the return value of `strtok()`, too before passing that to `strdup()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I will do this *(res + i -1) = NULL; the last data inside the array will be deleted. example:

when: *(res + i) = NULL;
res[0] = A
res[1] = B
res[2] = C
res[3] = D

but when *(res + i - 1) = NULL;
res[0] = A
res[1] = B
res[2] = C
res[3] = NULL